# Calculate years from each date in Oracle SQL

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper, oracle-apex

Noob question. I'm writing a script to execute a report showing: 
Student last name and first name (comma separated), years enrolled, academic advisor last name and first name (comma separated)
Sort: years enrolled
Filter: only include currently active students

Struggling with calculating years enrolled and filtering by active students.

The tables I'm using:
[image]

```
SELECT CONCAT(CONCAT(Student.Last_Name, ', '), Student.First_Name) AS "Student", 

Student_Enrollment_Status.Date_Status_Updated,

CONCAT(CONCAT(Faculty.Last_Name, ', '), Faculty.First_Name) AS "Advisor"

FROM Student

WHERE Faculty.Faculty_ID = Student.Advisor_ID

AND Student(Student_ID) = Student_Enrollment_Status(Student_ID)

AND Student_Enrollment_Status(Status_ID) = Enrollment_Status (Status_ID);
```

Comment: Consider [MONTHS_BETWEEN](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions089.htm) function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would be something like this:

- lines #1 - 22 represent sample data (you don't type that)
- query you need begins at line #24
- years enrolled is calculated by subtracting current year and year of enrollment; that's rather inaccurate, but - you didn't explain what *exactly* it means
- I presumed that active statuses are IDs (2, 3, 5)

---

```
SQL> with
  2  student (student_id, first_name, last_name, advisor_id) as
  3    (select 1, 'ash', 'smith', 9 from dual union all
  4     select 2, 'tash', 'paul', 8 from dual union all
  5     select 3, 'carl', 'wall', 6 from dual union all
  6     select 4, 'fred', 'john', 3 from dual),
  7  student_enrollment_status (student_id, status_id, date_status_updated) as
  8    (select 1, 2, date '2017-09-04' from dual union all
  9     select 2, 3, date '2018-09-05' from dual union all
 10     select 3, 3, date '2018-09-05' from dual union all
 11     select 4, 2, date '2019-09-04' from dual),
 12  enrollment_status (status_id, status) as
 13    (select 2, 'enrolled'  from dual union all
 14     select 3, 'on leave'  from dual union all
 15     select 4, 'full time' from dual union all
 16     select 5, 'part time' from dual union all
 17     select 6, 'withdrawn' from dual),
 18  faculty (faculty_id, first_name, last_name) as
 19    (select 9, 'jane', 'gold'  from dual union all
 20     select 8, 'sam', 'greene' from dual union all
 21     select 6, 'mark', 'west'  from dual union all
 22     select 3, 'jen', 'dash'   from dual)
 23  --
 24  select s.last_name ||', '|| s.first_name student,
 25    extract(year from sysdate) - extract(year from ses.date_status_updated)
 26      years_enrolled,
 27    f.last_name ||', '|| f.first_name advisor
 28  from student s join student_enrollment_status ses on ses.student_id = s.student_id
 29    join enrollment_status es on es.status_id = ses.status_id
 30    join faculty f on f.faculty_id = s.advisor_id
 31  where es.status_id in (2, 3, 5)
 32  order by years_enrolled;

STUDENT     YEARS_ENROLLED ADVISOR
----------- -------------- ------------
john, fred               1 dash, jen
paul, tash               2 greene, sam
wall, carl               2 west, mark
smith, ash               3 gold, jane

SQL>
```

Comment: Thanks alot! The concat this way seems simpler as well.